# PHP File has Status 302 when Wordpress Environment included

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-302

**General**

I'm using Wordpress and Ultimate Member 2 on my site to make user roles and permissions easy.

**What I try to do**

I want to update the user's role in an external PHP file using

`UM()->roles()->set_role($user_id, "um_verified-member");`

which should work.

But in order to use the `set_role` function, I need to include the Wordpress header into that PHP file. So I do that with

`require("../../../wp-blog-header.php");`

As soon as I include the Wordpress header I can see the status of the file changing from `200 OK` to `302 Found` and in the Response Headers of that file appears a `Location:` statement that points somewhere else.

Does anybody know whats going wrong here?

Thanks for the help,
Tim

Comment: try to include `wp-load.php`  file instead of `wp-blog-header.php`

Comment: and provide full code you used in external file

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out:

`require_once("../../../wp-load.php");`

works for me.

Thanks for the help!